# How to get Indexpath of cell in UITableView while clicking on Custom accessory Button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have UITableView.In  that i have created custom cell with accessory button.Now by clicking on accessory button i want to create another view with edit cell functionality.For that how do i find the index path of that cell?and how do i pass the vales of that cell?

How do i call following method:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: in that method only you are getting indexpath

Comment: is your button is custom ? if not then see the last argument of the method. It gives indexpath

Answer (score 84, accepted):

First thing to note here is that when you use custom *accessoryView* in a cell then the *tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:* delegate method would not be called. You have to add some target/action to the button you are adding as the custom accessory and handle the tap action yourself. You should add the custom accessory something like this,

```
UIButton *accessory = ...;
[accessory addTarget:self action:@selector(onCustomAccessoryTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
cell.accessoryView = accessory;
```

And in the *onCustomAccessoryTapped:* method you have to get the index path like this,

```
- (void)onCustomAccessoryTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Now you can do the following
    [self tableView:tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Or you can do something else here to handle the action
}
```

Comment: what if button is created in UITableViewCell ?

Comment: You mean "what if button is created inside *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* method"?

Comment: no... I am having custom cell by sub classing UITableViewCell. for that if I used above code then it returns UITableViewCellContainView !!!

Comment: This is old post i know but it helped me greatly. Thanks EmptyStack.

Comment: @EmptyStack Hi, may I suggest an edit to the answer: As it stands, I couldn't make it work, and checked here to see the same answer. The problem lies in the fact that the superview is now a UITableViewCellScrollView, therefore one must ascend two levels to get to the UITableViewCell. E.g. with (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview;

Comment: I think a more pertinent question is 'What if Apple unexpectedly change the structure of a UITableViewCell so that the accessory view's superview is no longer the cell itself?

Comment: @Maulik In that case you can try sender.superview.superview

Answer (score 3):

The indexPath is passed as the second parameter to the method.

Answer (score 3):

using "indexPathForCell" works as mentioned by emptystack

[yourViewController.tableView indexPathForCell: cell];

In addition if you are using tableview and a Search View, in your controller make sure to use searchDisplayController

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath;
NSDictionary *campaignMember;
if(self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
        indexPath = [[self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView] indexPathForCell: cell];
        campaignMember = [self.filterResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: cell];
    campaignMember = [self.dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
NSString *id = [campaignMember objectForKey:@"Id"];
```

In my case "campaignMember" is a person object and I needed to get its id. "self.dataRows" is an array that holds main table data where as "self.filterResults" contains a subset or search/filter results of all the data based on search/filter criteria.